# Couchdb docker on WSL2: no setup possible

Tags: docker, couchdb

I was trying to have some fun with Docker and test out CouchDB.
I'm working on a Docker on Windows 10 running on WSL2.

I understood that it was easy enough to run something like:

```
docker run -d --name my-couchdb -e COUCHDB_USER=admin -e COUCHDB_PASSWORD=password couchdb:latest -p 5984:5984
```

And actually, it is running "fine."

Fine in the sense that I can see from the logs that it is running ok, with no error.

But at this point, I wanted to set it up, going to http://127.0.0.1:5984/_utils#setup or http://[::1]:5984/_utils#setup

As you can imagine, I cannot access it.

Any idea on how to troubleshoot it?
I'm no expert in docker, and it is the first time on CouchDB, so I wanted to have a quick run, but I'm already stuck.

Thanks,
Ro

Comment: your parameter -p should be put before you define the image.

Comment: @SKos It worked! I'm surprised though it made so much difference! Could you explain me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per documentation here https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/

```
docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

item you put after the image will be act as arguments which is not what you want here.